# Visual C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Can I install standalone Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler on my Windows 8.1 x86 machine and how much data I need to download?
And how much data i need to download required files to install Visual Studio 2015 Build tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the Build Tools without the IDE:

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Some details concerning the 2017 Build Tools:

> These Build Tools allow you to build native and managed MSBuild-based applications without requiring the Visual Studio IDE. There are options to install the Visual C++ compilers and libraries, MFC, ATL, and C++/CLI support, and .NET and .NET Core support.

You can also follow the descriptions here: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: You helped me alot 

Answer (score 0):

can you please describe your question properly

According to your question

Yes you can install standalone Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler.
download required files to install Visual Studio 2015 Build tools? - 24mb of file

go to this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159 for downloading

Comment: I just wanted to know size of VS build tool. Alright, i got my answer. Thanks